# SQL: How to join hierarchical table relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables which are `Department`, `Office`, `Division`

Supposed flow is: `Department has Offices has Divisions`

But there are instances that `Divisions` reports directly to `Departments`

Example Data

```
Department   Office                Division
[id][name]   [dept_id][id][name]   [dept_id][off_id][id][name]
[ 1][A   ]   [     1 ][ 1][D   ]   [     1 ][    2 ][ 1][G   ]
[ 2][B   ]   [     1 ][ 2][E   ]   [     3 ][ NULL ][ 2][H   ]
[ 3][C   ]   [     3 ][ 3][F   ]   [     3 ][   3  ][ 3][I   ]
```

Desired Output to display all **Divisions**:

```
OUTPUT
[AS dept_name][AS off_name][AS div_name]
[      A     ][     E     ][     G     ]
[      C     ][    NULL   ][     H     ]
[      C     ][     F     ][     I     ]
```

My current Query is:

```
    SELECT * FROM `Division` A 
    RIGHT JOIN `Office` B ON A.`off_id` = B.`id` 
    RIGHT JOIN `Department` C ON A.`dept_id` = C.`id`;
```

my query is wrong, so i'm looking for a way to join those 3 table to achieve the desired output

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my query is wrong, so i'm looking for a way to join those 3 table to achieve the desired output

Comment: I think you just need to join with divisions two times with two different aliases, e.g. A1 and A2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to to display **all divisions**, it is necessary to use `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  Department.`name` AS dept_name, 
  Office.`name` AS off_name,
  Division.`name` AS div_name
FROM
  Division 
  LEFT JOIN Office ON Division.off_id = Office.id
  LEFT JOIN Department ON Division`.dept_id = Department.id;
```